# Best practices to Manage Database project in TFS and visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, tfs

Currently , we don't have our stored procedures , and everything else related to the proj in TFS , we are managing everything on Server ( Adding , Fixing , removing stored procedured , tables etc) We would like to start manage everything via tfs and visual studio.

Is there any best practices on how to manage this stuff ? I didn't read about Sql Server 2005 Visual studio template and doesn't know what it does , but is there any way to create a project in VS , connect to existing DataBase , and be able to track changes of procedures , in TFS ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can create a database project and import objects from the database you want to manage.  You can start [with this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193419(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can!  But I do not recommend the database projects that come with VS 2010 out of the box anymore - they are great,  but there is a newer version available. Basically the SQL Server team at Microsoft took ownership of the database project features and has released those features as SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). This is a free download from the Microsoft site. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx

SSDT integrates with either VS 2010 or VS 2012. When you use it to create a database project, it will generate a CREATE script for each object in your database so that you can keep them under version control and compare versions over time. It also has other features like db deployment, unit testing for databases and static code analysis of T-SQL.

Comment: I would agree with Ryan. The SSDT database project is the more recent incarnation and there are very few reasons why you shouldn't use these in preference to the older style database projects.

Comment: Being stuck on xp would be one.

Comment: @JamesWoolfenden, I pity you.